# Tomcat inside eclipse-server started successfully but

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat8

If I start apache tomcat server by clicking the startup.bat from the Apache bin folder it starts successfully and I can access http://localhost:8080/ from IE. I get the message Apache Tomcat is successful.
But......

In eclipse Luna, I have setup tomcat server(8). And started the server. Now when I go to Internet explorer and type in http://localhost:8080/  i'm getting error.
http status 404
The requested resource not available.

Answer (score 0):

Open **Servers** view in Eclipse, double-click to open configuration of Tomcat.
If you don't have a **Web Modules** deployed in path `/`. Tomcat will return 404 error.

When you start Tomcat by startup.bat, it will load **Web Modules** under `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps`. The **ROOT** module will serve the request of path `/`, so Tomcat could display a page without error.